# Nested map function returning array of objects with index as key value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to reformat some data from an API and I'm having trouble getting it the way I need. I need everything to be flattened and my second map function (attMap) is returning them with the an index as the key value?

```
var attMap = products.items.map( x => x.custom_attributes.map( y => ( {[y.attribute_code]: y.value} )));
```

You can see my first map function (prodMap) works properly.

```
var prodMap = products.items.map( x => ({ name: x.name, sku: x.sku }));
```

You can see the result in this image after merging them:

```
newArray = [];

prodMap.forEach((itm, i)=> {
  newArray.push(Object.assign({}, itm, attMap[i]));
});
```

[image]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dkx9qewt/

I'm not the best programmer but is my attMap map function returning an array of objects because it's nested? Is that the issue?

Edit: The output I'm looking for is something like:

```
["Description":"Product Description","Short Description":"shortdescription","Surname":"surname","Length":"6","Tip Configuration":"Blunt","Instrument Type":"Hemostatic Forceps","Curvature":"Curved","Working Surface Style":"Serrated with Longitudinal Groove","Handle":"Finger Rings","Material":"Stainless Steel","Disposable or Reusable":"Reusable",Sterile or Non-Sterile":"Non-Sterile","Latex or Latex-Free":"Latex-Free","Grade":"Premium OR-Grade","name":"Product 1","sku":"4242"}
```

Instead of:

```
[{"0":{"Description":"Product Description"},"1":{"Short Description":"shortdescription"},"2":{"Surname":"surname"},"3":{"Length":"6"},"4":{"Tip Configuration":"Blunt"},"5":{"Instrument Type":"Hemostatic Forceps"},"6":{"Curvature":"Curved"},"7":{"Working Surface Style":"Serrated with Longitudinal Groove"},"8":{"Handle":"Finger Rings"},"9":{"Material":"Stainless Steel"},"10":{"Disposable or Reusable":"Reusable"},"11":{"Sterile or Non-Sterile":"Non-Sterile"},"12":{"Latex or Latex-Free":"Latex-Free"},"13":{"Grade":"Premium OR-Grade"},"name":"Product 1","sku":"4242"}
```

Comment: What is the intended output?

Comment: You should consider using `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` to look at the actual object structure. Chrome's method of showing objects is often more confusing than it needs to be.

Comment: probably `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)` for better readability though :)

Comment: @user633183 The intended output would be for the key to be, Description, Short Description, Surname, etc.. instead of (0,1,2,3). Similar to how name and sku currently work.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks, that certainly makes it easier to read, although I'm still stumped.
{"0":{"Description":"Product Description"},"1":{"Short Description":"shortdescription"}

Would need to be:

{Description":"Product Description","Short Description":"shortdescription"}

Comment: @user633183 I updated the original questions.

Comment: Note the reason is likely because you're using `map`, which returns an array, which naturally has numeric indexes. You probably want to switch to `reduce` to build an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a technique that involves breaking the problem down into sensible parts -

```js
const products =
  {items:[{id:0,sku:"4242",name:"Product 1",attributeSetId:0,price:0,status:0,visibility:0,typeId:"string",createdAt:"string",updatedAt:"string",weight:0,extensionAttributes:[],productLinks:[],options:[],mediaGalleryEntries:[],tierPrices:[],custom_attributes:[{attribute_code:"Description","value":"Product Description"},{attribute_code:"Short Description","value":"shortdescription"},{attribute_code:"Surname","value":"surname"},{attribute_code:"Length","value":"6"},{attribute_code:"Tip Configuration","value":"Blunt"},{attribute_code:"Instrument Type","value":"Hemostatic Forceps"},{attribute_code:"Curvature","value":"Curved"},{attribute_code:"Working Surface Style","value":"Serrated with Longitudinal Groove"},{attribute_code:"Handle","value":"Finger Rings"},{attribute_code:"Material","value":"Stainless Steel"},{attribute_code:"Disposable or Reusable","value":"Reusable"},{attribute_code:"Sterile or Non-Sterile","value":"Non-Sterile"},{attribute_code:"Latex or Latex-Free","value":"Latex-Free"},{attribute_code:"Grade","value":"Premium OR-Grade"}]},{id:0,sku:"5252",name:"Product 2",attributeSetId:0,price:0,status:0,visibility:0,typeId:"string",createdAt:"string",updatedAt:"string",weight:0,extensionAttributes:[],productLinks:[],options:[],mediaGalleryEntries:[],tierPrices:[],custom_attributes:[{attribute_code:"Description","value":"Product Description"},{attribute_code:"Short Description","value":"shortdescription"},{attribute_code:"Surname","value":"surname"},{attribute_code:"Length","value":"4"},{attribute_code:"Tip Configuration","value":"Square End"},{attribute_code:"Instrument Type","value":"Glass Forceps"},{attribute_code:"Curvature","value":"Angled"},{attribute_code:"Working Surface Style","value":"Smooth"},{attribute_code:"Handle","value":"Thumb"},{attribute_code:"Material","value":"Stainless Steel"},{attribute_code:"Disposable or Reusable","value":"Reusable"},{attribute_code:"Sterile or Non-Sterile","value":"Non-Sterile"},{attribute_code:"Latex or Latex-Free","value":"Latex-Free"},{attribute_code:"Grade","value":"Premium OR-Grade"}]},{id:0,sku:"4243",name:"Product 3",attributeSetId:0,price:0,status:0,visibility:0,typeId:"string",createdAt:"string",updatedAt:"string",weight:0,extensionAttributes:[],productLinks:[],options:[],mediaGalleryEntries:[],tierPrices:[],custom_attributes:[{attribute_code:"Description","value":"Product Description"},{attribute_code:"Short Description","value":"shortdescription"},{attribute_code:"Surname","value":"surname"},{attribute_code:"Length","value":"6"},{attribute_code:"Tip Configuration","value":"Blunt"},{attribute_code:"Instrument Type","value":"Hemostatic Forceps"},{attribute_code:"Curvature","value":"Curved"},{attribute_code:"Working Surface Style","value":"Serrated with Longitudinal Groove"},{attribute_code:"Handle","value":"Finger Rings"},{attribute_code:"Material","value":"Stainless Steel"},{attribute_code:"Disposable or Reusable","value":"Reusable"},{attribute_code:"Sterile or Non-Sterile","value":"Non-Sterile"},{attribute_code:"Latex or Latex-Free","value":"Latex-Free"},{attribute_code:"Grade","value":"Premium OR-Grade"}]},{id:0,sku:"5254",name:"Product 4",attributeSetId:0,price:0,status:0,visibility:0,typeId:"string",createdAt:"string",updatedAt:"string",weight:0,extensionAttributes:[],productLinks:[],options:[],mediaGalleryEntries:[],tierPrices:[],custom_attributes:[{attribute_code:"Description","value":"Product Description"},{attribute_code:"Short Description","value":"shortdescription"},{attribute_code:"Surname","value":"surname"},{attribute_code:"Length","value":"4"},{attribute_code:"Tip Configuration","value":"Square End"},{attribute_code:"Instrument Type","value":"Glass Forceps"},{attribute_code:"Curvature","value":"Angled"},{attribute_code:"Working Surface Style","value":"Smooth"},{attribute_code:"Handle","value":"Thumb"},{attribute_code:"Material","value":"Stainless Steel"},{attribute_code:"Disposable or Reusable","value":"Reusable"},{attribute_code:"Sterile or Non-Sterile","value":"Non-Sterile"},{attribute_code:"Latex or Latex-Free","value":"Latex-Free"},{attribute_code:"Grade","value":"Premium OR-Grade"}]}]}

const flattenAttributes = ({ custom_attributes = [], ...product }) =>
{ const mergeAttribute = (r = {}, { attribute_code = "", value = "" }) =>
    Object.assign(r, { [attribute_code]: value })

  const flat =
    custom_attributes.reduce(mergeAttribute, {})

  return { ...product, custom_attributes: flat } 
}

console.log(products.items.map(flattenAttributes))
```

Here's the output -

```
[ { id: 0,
    sku: '4242',
    name: 'Product 1',
    attributeSetId: 0,
    price: 0,
    status: 0,
    visibility: 0,
    typeId: 'string',
    createdAt: 'string',
    updatedAt: 'string',
    weight: 0,
    extensionAttributes: [],
    productLinks: [],
    options: [],
    mediaGalleryEntries: [],
    tierPrices: [],
    custom_attributes:
     { Description: 'Product Description',
       'Short Description': 'shortdescription',
       Surname: 'surname',
       Length: '6',
       'Tip Configuration': 'Blunt',
       'Instrument Type': 'Hemostatic Forceps',
       Curvature: 'Curved',
       'Working Surface Style': 'Serrated with Longitudinal Groove',
       Handle: 'Finger Rings',
       Material: 'Stainless Steel',
       'Disposable or Reusable': 'Reusable',
       'Sterile or Non-Sterile': 'Non-Sterile',
       'Latex or Latex-Free': 'Latex-Free',
       Grade: 'Premium OR-Grade' } },

  ... ]
```

---

If you just want `name` and `sku` inline with `custom_attributes`, consider this slight modification -

```js
const products =
  {items:[{id:0,sku:"4242",name:"Product 1",attributeSetId:0,price:0,status:0,visibility:0,typeId:"string",createdAt:"string",updatedAt:"string",weight:0,extensionAttributes:[],productLinks:[],options:[],mediaGalleryEntries:[],tierPrices:[],custom_attributes:[{attribute_code:"Description","value":"Product Description"},{attribute_code:"Short Description","value":"shortdescription"},{attribute_code:"Surname","value":"surname"},{attribute_code:"Length","value":"6"},{attribute_code:"Tip Configuration","value":"Blunt"},{attribute_code:"Instrument Type","value":"Hemostatic Forceps"},{attribute_code:"Curvature","value":"Curved"},{attribute_code:"Working Surface Style","value":"Serrated with Longitudinal Groove"},{attribute_code:"Handle","value":"Finger Rings"},{attribute_code:"Material","value":"Stainless Steel"},{attribute_code:"Disposable or Reusable","value":"Reusable"},{attribute_code:"Sterile or Non-Sterile","value":"Non-Sterile"},{attribute_code:"Latex or Latex-Free","value":"Latex-Free"},{attribute_code:"Grade","value":"Premium OR-Grade"}]},{id:0,sku:"5252",name:"Product 2",attributeSetId:0,price:0,status:0,visibility:0,typeId:"string",createdAt:"string",updatedAt:"string",weight:0,extensionAttributes:[],productLinks:[],options:[],mediaGalleryEntries:[],tierPrices:[],custom_attributes:[{attribute_code:"Description","value":"Product Description"},{attribute_code:"Short Description","value":"shortdescription"},{attribute_code:"Surname","value":"surname"},{attribute_code:"Length","value":"4"},{attribute_code:"Tip Configuration","value":"Square End"},{attribute_code:"Instrument Type","value":"Glass Forceps"},{attribute_code:"Curvature","value":"Angled"},{attribute_code:"Working Surface Style","value":"Smooth"},{attribute_code:"Handle","value":"Thumb"},{attribute_code:"Material","value":"Stainless Steel"},{attribute_code:"Disposable or Reusable","value":"Reusable"},{attribute_code:"Sterile or Non-Sterile","value":"Non-Sterile"},{attribute_code:"Latex or Latex-Free","value":"Latex-Free"},{attribute_code:"Grade","value":"Premium OR-Grade"}]},{id:0,sku:"4243",name:"Product 3",attributeSetId:0,price:0,status:0,visibility:0,typeId:"string",createdAt:"string",updatedAt:"string",weight:0,extensionAttributes:[],productLinks:[],options:[],mediaGalleryEntries:[],tierPrices:[],custom_attributes:[{attribute_code:"Description","value":"Product Description"},{attribute_code:"Short Description","value":"shortdescription"},{attribute_code:"Surname","value":"surname"},{attribute_code:"Length","value":"6"},{attribute_code:"Tip Configuration","value":"Blunt"},{attribute_code:"Instrument Type","value":"Hemostatic Forceps"},{attribute_code:"Curvature","value":"Curved"},{attribute_code:"Working Surface Style","value":"Serrated with Longitudinal Groove"},{attribute_code:"Handle","value":"Finger Rings"},{attribute_code:"Material","value":"Stainless Steel"},{attribute_code:"Disposable or Reusable","value":"Reusable"},{attribute_code:"Sterile or Non-Sterile","value":"Non-Sterile"},{attribute_code:"Latex or Latex-Free","value":"Latex-Free"},{attribute_code:"Grade","value":"Premium OR-Grade"}]},{id:0,sku:"5254",name:"Product 4",attributeSetId:0,price:0,status:0,visibility:0,typeId:"string",createdAt:"string",updatedAt:"string",weight:0,extensionAttributes:[],productLinks:[],options:[],mediaGalleryEntries:[],tierPrices:[],custom_attributes:[{attribute_code:"Description","value":"Product Description"},{attribute_code:"Short Description","value":"shortdescription"},{attribute_code:"Surname","value":"surname"},{attribute_code:"Length","value":"4"},{attribute_code:"Tip Configuration","value":"Square End"},{attribute_code:"Instrument Type","value":"Glass Forceps"},{attribute_code:"Curvature","value":"Angled"},{attribute_code:"Working Surface Style","value":"Smooth"},{attribute_code:"Handle","value":"Thumb"},{attribute_code:"Material","value":"Stainless Steel"},{attribute_code:"Disposable or Reusable","value":"Reusable"},{attribute_code:"Sterile or Non-Sterile","value":"Non-Sterile"},{attribute_code:"Latex or Latex-Free","value":"Latex-Free"},{attribute_code:"Grade","value":"Premium OR-Grade"}]}]}
  
const flattenAttributes = ({ name = "", sku = "", custom_attributes = [] }) =>
{ const mergeAttribute = (r = {}, { attribute_code = "", value = "" }) =>
    Object.assign(r, { [attribute_code]: value })

  const flat =
    custom_attributes.reduce(mergeAttribute, {})

  return { ...flat, name, sku } 
}

console.log(products.items.map(flattenAttributes))
```

This matches your expected output -

```
[ { Description: 'Product Description',
    'Short Description': 'shortdescription',
    Surname: 'surname',
    Length: '6',
    'Tip Configuration': 'Blunt',
    'Instrument Type': 'Hemostatic Forceps',
    Curvature: 'Curved',
    'Working Surface Style': 'Serrated with Longitudinal Groove',
    Handle: 'Finger Rings',
    Material: 'Stainless Steel',
    'Disposable or Reusable': 'Reusable',
    'Sterile or Non-Sterile': 'Non-Sterile',
    'Latex or Latex-Free': 'Latex-Free',
    Grade: 'Premium OR-Grade',
    name: 'Product 1',
    sku: '4242' },

  ... ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.map always returns an array, since what you want is a generic object, map is not what you want.

```js
var products = {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "sku": "4242",
            "name": "Product 1",
            "attributeSetId": 0,
            "price": 0,
            "status": 0,
            "visibility": 0,
            "typeId": "string",
            "createdAt": "string",
            "updatedAt": "string",
            "weight": 0,
            "extensionAttributes": [],
            "productLinks": [],
            "options": [],
            "mediaGalleryEntries": [],
            "tierPrices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Description",
                    "value" : "Product Description"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Short Description",
                    "value" : "shortdescription"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Surname",
                    "value" : "surname"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Length",
                    "value" : "6"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Tip Configuration",
                    "value" : "Blunt"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Instrument Type",
                    "value" : "Hemostatic Forceps"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Curvature",
                    "value" : "Curved"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Working Surface Style",
                    "value" : "Serrated with Longitudinal Groove"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Handle",
                    "value" : "Finger Rings"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Material",
                    "value" : "Stainless Steel"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Disposable or Reusable",
                    "value" : "Reusable"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Sterile or Non-Sterile",
                    "value" : "Non-Sterile"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Latex or Latex-Free",
                    "value" : "Latex-Free"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Grade",
                    "value" : "Premium OR-Grade"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "sku": "5252",
            "name": "Product 2",
            "attributeSetId": 0,
            "price": 0,
            "status": 0,
            "visibility": 0,
            "typeId": "string",
            "createdAt": "string",
            "updatedAt": "string",
            "weight": 0,
            "extensionAttributes": [],
            "productLinks": [],
            "options": [],
            "mediaGalleryEntries": [],
            "tierPrices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Description",
                    "value" : "Product Description"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Short Description",
                    "value" : "shortdescription"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Surname",
                    "value" : "surname"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Length",
                    "value" : "4"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Tip Configuration",
                    "value" : "Square End"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Instrument Type",
                    "value" : "Glass Forceps"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Curvature",
                    "value" : "Angled"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Working Surface Style",
                    "value" : "Smooth"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Handle",
                    "value" : "Thumb"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Material",
                    "value" : "Stainless Steel"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Disposable or Reusable",
                    "value" : "Reusable"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Sterile or Non-Sterile",
                    "value" : "Non-Sterile"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Latex or Latex-Free",
                    "value" : "Latex-Free"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Grade",
                    "value" : "Premium OR-Grade"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "sku": "4243",
            "name": "Product 3",
            "attributeSetId": 0,
            "price": 0,
            "status": 0,
            "visibility": 0,
            "typeId": "string",
            "createdAt": "string",
            "updatedAt": "string",
            "weight": 0,
            "extensionAttributes": [],
            "productLinks": [],
            "options": [],
            "mediaGalleryEntries": [],
            "tierPrices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Description",
                    "value" : "Product Description"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Short Description",
                    "value" : "shortdescription"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Surname",
                    "value" : "surname"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Length",
                    "value" : "6"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Tip Configuration",
                    "value" : "Blunt"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Instrument Type",
                    "value" : "Hemostatic Forceps"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Curvature",
                    "value" : "Curved"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Working Surface Style",
                    "value" : "Serrated with Longitudinal Groove"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Handle",
                    "value" : "Finger Rings"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Material",
                    "value" : "Stainless Steel"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Disposable or Reusable",
                    "value" : "Reusable"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Sterile or Non-Sterile",
                    "value" : "Non-Sterile"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Latex or Latex-Free",
                    "value" : "Latex-Free"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Grade",
                    "value" : "Premium OR-Grade"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "sku": "5254",
            "name": "Product 4",
            "attributeSetId": 0,
            "price": 0,
            "status": 0,
            "visibility": 0,
            "typeId": "string",
            "createdAt": "string",
            "updatedAt": "string",
            "weight": 0,
            "extensionAttributes": [],
            "productLinks": [],
            "options": [],
            "mediaGalleryEntries": [],
            "tierPrices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Description",
                    "value" : "Product Description"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Short Description",
                    "value" : "shortdescription"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Surname",
                    "value" : "surname"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Length",
                    "value" : "4"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Tip Configuration",
                    "value" : "Square End"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Instrument Type",
                    "value" : "Glass Forceps"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Curvature",
                    "value" : "Angled"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Working Surface Style",
                    "value" : "Smooth"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Handle",
                    "value" : "Thumb"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Material",
                    "value" : "Stainless Steel"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Disposable or Reusable",
                    "value" : "Reusable"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Sterile or Non-Sterile",
                    "value" : "Non-Sterile"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Latex or Latex-Free",
                    "value" : "Latex-Free"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code" : "Grade",
                    "value" : "Premium OR-Grade"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


var prodMap = [];
products.items.forEach( x => {
  var obj = {};
  x.custom_attributes.forEach( o => {
    obj[o.attribute_code] = o.value;
  });
  prodMap.push(obj);
});

console.log(prodMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### For those who are looking for code:

As suggested in the comments, the `Object.assign()` method *(see [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign))* does the trick.

```
var modifiedAtt = attMap.map(item => item.reduce((acc, i)=> Object.assign({}, acc, i)))
```

this gives the expected output. Tested on `node v10.12.0` with `JavaScript`.

#### For other readers:

`Object.assign(target, sourceObj1, sourceObj2...)` takes the first argument as the target and copy the values of all enumerable own properties of the other arguments (Objects) into the target Object, overwriting any that have the same key. `Object.assign()` returns the modified `target` Object.

The `Array.reduce(function(sum, currentArrayValue, index, array), startValue)` method ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) iterates over all values of an Array reducing the Array to a single value (sum). It takes a function as it's first argument, with the second, optional, argument being the starting value of the sum. The arguments for that function are an accumulator, the current value of the Array, the current index, and the Array itself. The function returns the new value of the accumulator, which is then passes to the function in the next iteration, or is the value returned from the `.reduce()` after the last Array value is operated upon.